# Django and JQuery - Find and Replace Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to transfer data from one tag to the other.

This is how far I got:

```
<a id="oldartist"> {{ object.user }}</a>
<a id="newartist"></a>


function newArt() {
    var artistname = document.getElementById("oldartist");
    $('#newartist').text(artistname);
};
```

---

But I get

```
https:// mywebsite.com/johndoe
```

instead of

```
johndoe
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the `<a>` element as is into the tag, it needs to be,

```
function newArt() {
   var artistname = document.getElementById("oldartist").text;
   $('#newartist').text(artistname);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I check if a src of an img tag is empty?

Comment: You can use `if ($('#myImg').attr('src') == '') {alert("no src")}`